# Connecting to the server which password contains "@" symbols using ftp protocol

Tags: java, ftp

I am trying to download files from a server using FTP protocol in java.
By using following URL I am able to connect to the server & download files.

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://"+user+":"+password+"@"+host+"/"+remoteFile+";type=i");
```

But when my password contains the "@" (ex : soft@2011) symbol it throws the following exception:

```
  java.net.UnknownHostException: 2010@192.168.1.100
```

It is not able to differentiate both "@" symbols.

How can I avoid this problem?  Can I use any escape characters to avoid this problem?

Comment: if you write `user:passwor\@d` isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[URI encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the password (and preferably the user name as well) should work just fine.

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://" + 
                  URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8") + ":" + 
                  URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "@" + 
                  host + "/" + remoteFile + ";type=i");
```

Comment: @mateuszb `encode(String)` is deprecated, but `encode(String,String)` ain't

Answer (score 1):

Try and use URI instead:

```
final URI ftpURI = new URI("ftp", "user@pass", host, 22, remoteFile, null, null);
```

Then use:

```
ftpURI.toURL()
```

This should normally give you what is expected.