# Java : URL with @ symbol in ftp connection

Tags: java, url, ftp, url-encoding

Following the question [Connecting to the server which password contains "@" symbols using ftp protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489220/connecting-to-the-server-which-password-contains-symbols-using-ftp-protocol/), the answer is right. URLEncoder encodes @ into %. But let's say password already contains % and I am not encoding it, then how URL class will get to know that password in not encoded one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser (or method that is parsing the FTP URL) is URL Decoding the password.  So if you don't URL Encode the password and you pass a % it will attempt to decode it anyways and therefor won't work. The same thing applies to @ and :.  [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/60443/encoding-in-ftp-user-password-within-url) over on Super User includes more detailed proof that this is in fact what is happening (they inspected the raw TCP/IP traffic with Wireshark to see what was being passed).